# running motors from ownely coupled generator

Tags: motor, 12v

i want to do the experiment on motor generator
my design is iamgoing to connect a 2 dc motors and 2 dc generators in that 1st dc motor and 1st dc generator is coupled 1st dc motor and 2nd dc motor are coupled supply is given to both motors using a switch the 2nd dc motor is coupled to 2nd dc generator when supply is on the motors will run and iam going to generate voltage from both generators now iam going to take the voltage of 2nd dc generato and give it to the coupled motors by switch off the dc mains and iam going to take the output from 1st dc generator now my question is whether it will works and what are all needed to do this project

Comment: It is a youtube trick. Can you please complete your profile in order to receive the best answer?

Comment: 1: Wall of text needs punctuation & formatting for readbaility. 2: Perpetual motion doesn't work.

Comment: Perpetual Motion malarkey seen on YouTube is nonsense and cannot realistically be talked about on a serious Q&A medium.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "work". I expect it will work perfectly  - at proving the law of conservation of energy, by losing power as heat and stopping. What do you want to get out of this experiment?

Comment: Why do you need all of this mess? Just connect two wheels with a belt. The first wheel will spin the second one. The second will spin the first one. Oh wait! Why do you need the second wheel and the belt at all?? Just have a single wheel. The upper part will move the lower one, and the lower one will move the upper. Yeah. Should work. Exactly as your proposed setup.

Comment: There are many websites and You tube videos which tell you that you can get more energy from a system than you put in. Very sadly, NONE of them work. Any system that provides energy out needs to have an energy source - a battery or solar power or fuel or ... . It may be fun to try what you descrbe but you can be completely certain that it will not work. Very sadly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I would say it's fortunate, not sadly.

Comment: When asking questions you MUST make some effort to punctuate your sentences properly. You need sentences with full stops, capital letters at the start of sentences, words not run together (such as "iam") and some paragraphs. If you do not do this people will not read your posts and will vote to close them even if the content is OK.

Comment: It is extremely sad, sadly :-), that all you smart gentleman choose to have fun at the expense of an honest inquirer or just rubbish his query, rather than providing some guidance on the path to enlightenment.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The "fortunate" thing was really serious. Conservation laws are *absolutely necessary* to maintain the symmetry and balance in the Universe. Consider you come up with an infinite source of energy. Especially such a simple one. Then every one on their own kitchen can build, say, a laser able to ..hm.. destroy the Moon (well, not every one, but 1% of these having a kitchen, which is a lot..)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Now you just have to deal with your prior comment:-) :-( My point is that this sort of response i great phone for the boys, apparently, but drives off newcomers who should arguably be at least given a chance. Some say not. | When I was 10 or 11 years old I "paper--designed" a PMM based on transformers and vacuum cleaner motors and similar. I took the diagrams to my school teacher who said he though it would not work BUT could not explain why. Having someone say why in other people's case seems like a good idea (even if it's on;y "because"). ...

Comment: @EugeneSh. ...  And, yes, I'm aware of the place of conservation laws.   Alas :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon No, I am not going to deal with that :) It comes to show the absurdness of all of the similar setups which are based on pumping the energy back and forth between different types.

Answer (score 2):

> ... My question is whether it will work ...

What you describe is known as a "perpetual motion machine" or sometimes an "over unity" device.  None of them work.
Not ever.
Sadly.

There are many websites and You tube videos which tell you that you can get more energy from a system than you put in. Very sadly, NONE of them work.

Any system that provides energy out needs to have an energy source - a battery or solar power or fuel or ... .

It may be fun to try what you describe but you can be completely certain that it will not work.
Very sadly